# Intent doesn't work

Tags: android, android-intent, countdowntimer

as you gues I  have a problem...

I have this code in my Islem.java class

```
public void myFinish(){
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setClassName(this, SaveScore.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

if I write `myFinish();` in `onCreate` method it works fine

However, in timer.java class

```
public void onFinish() {
    Islem is = new Islem();
    is.myFinish();
}
```

when I use this code boom Error! :)

The strange thing is that when I change the `myFinish` code to

```
 public void myFinish(){

 /*     Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setClassName(this, SaveScore.class);
    startActivity(i);*/

    time.setText("Finish!");
}
```

Even though I use it in timer.jawa class it works just fine!

LogCat
    03-16 14:27:14.370: E/AndroidRuntime(29940): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    03-16 14:27:14.370: E/AndroidRuntime(29940): java.lang.NullPointerException
    03-16 14:27:14.370: E/AndroidRuntime(29940):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2833)
    03-16 14:27:14.370: E/AndroidRuntime(29940):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2959)
    03-16 14:27:14.370: E/AndroidRuntime(29940):    at com.edusoftgame.kidsmath.Islem.myFinish(Islem.java:323)
03-16 14:27:14.370: E/AndroidRuntime(29940):    at com.edusoftgame.kidsmath.Timer.onFinish(Timer.java:19)
03-16 14:27:14.370: E/AndroidRuntime(29940):    at android.os.CountDownTimer$1.handleMessage(CountDownTimer.java:118)
03-16 14:27:14.370: E/AndroidRuntime(29940):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-16 14:27:14.370: E/AndroidRuntime(29940):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
03-16 14:27:14.370: E/AndroidRuntime(29940):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3693)
03-16 14:27:14.370: E/AndroidRuntime(29940):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-16 14:27:14.370: E/AndroidRuntime(29940):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-16 14:27:14.370: E/AndroidRuntime(29940):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
03-16 14:27:14.370: E/AndroidRuntime(29940):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
03-16 14:27:14.370: E/AndroidRuntime(29940):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Any Idea? Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Murali. Do not extend your class with CountDownTimer. Extend with Activity only.

If you want to use CountDownTimer, then use like this way -

```
    CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
```

In your method :

```
public void myfininsh(){

    countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(longvalue,500) {

@Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                System.out.println("Enabled");

            }
        }.start();
}
}
```

This will definitely solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this snip code:

```
public void myFinish(){
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setClassName(this, SaveScore.class);
startActivity(i)
```

;

Answer (score 0):

Try this, instead of `this use` your `activity name`.

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SaveScore.class);
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

May your class name reference not getting try like,

```
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setClassName(YourclassName.this, SaveScore.class);
    startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this...

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setClassName(your package name, your class name);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: When I use that
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setClassName(getApplicationContext(),SaveScore.class);
    StartActivity(i); 
setClassName gives error

Comment: it underlines setClassName in red, but when I shift it to i.setClassName("com.softgame.kidsmath", "com.softgame.kidsmath.SaveScore");
        no error but still doesnt work

Comment: try yo make changes like in setClassName()- 1. give only your package name 2. as second parameter give full class name (with package)

Answer (score 0):

Have timer.java class not extended Activity or Serivce yet?

Method :

```
public void myFinish(){
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setClassName(this, SaveScore.class);
startActivity(i);
```

}

work fine because you wrote in onCreate() of Activity.

Comment: timer.java does not extens Activity it  extends CountDownTimer
So, what shoul I do?